# Warning on sip.xml in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, sip-servlet

I have a sip.xml (for SIP servlets)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<sip-app>
...
</sip-app>
```

and I get the Eclipse warning `No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document.`

How can I fix it?
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified `<sip-app>` to  `<sip-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.jcp.org/xml/ns/sipservlet" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jcp.org/xml/ns/sipservlet http://www.jcp.org/xml/ns/sipservlet/sip-app_1_1.xsd">`.
Problem solved!